# How to select the element in HTML tags based on its text in Behat?

Tags: behat, mink

I'm running the following Behat scenario:

```
Then I should see "Testing body" in the "strong" element
```

for the following HTML snippet:

```
<strong>Testing body</strong>
```

However I am getting an error:

> The text "Testing body" was not found in the text of the element matching css "strong"

What is the best way to check if element contains below tags?

```
<em>Testing body</em>
<ol><li>Testing body</li>
</ol>
<ul><li>Testing body​​​​​​​</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to use [`wysiwyg.feature`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/wetkit_test/tree/tests/features/wysiwyg.feature?id=be6f04232e257ec97dc4bbd1726e636ea370d6bc#n18) with syntax:

```
Then I should see "Testing body" in the "<Element>" element with the "<Property>" CSS property set to "<Value>" in the "Pearson Content" region
```

Comment: The feature file does not help, you need to check the page for selectors, possible that the navigation to the page is slow and finds other strong element or you have other strong element before the one that contains this text. Provide, if possible, a larger section of the html code that contains this element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the selector used is unique.

Depending on the method used you might need id|name|label|value or css selector.

I your case the selector used is too general, you need to narrow the section by adding an extra element in front of this to tell him to search in a smaller section.

For example: `#myid` strong -> will search strong in the element that has the id myid

Same thing for the other elements, you could have ol>li or ul>li, but if more elements are found you will need to add an extra selector in front to narrow the section.

Always check the CSS manually in the browser and make sure is unique or the element that you need is found first.

If you want to check for an element that contains some text, you could use XPath like this:

```
//strong[contains(text(), 'Testing body')]
```

You can also use a css if you can identify this section as I said above, but I need more from the html, a large section in order to get a better selector.

Comment: my html snipet is <p class=""><strong class="">Testing body</strong></p>
don't have any class or id attached to it. how do i select?

Answer (score 1):

The following method may help:

```
/**
 * @Given I should see :text in the :tag element
 */
public function iShouldSeeInTheElement($text, $tag) {
  $this->verifyElementByXpath("//${tag}[contains(text(), '${text}')]");
}
```

Instead of [`contains`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains), you can also use [`starts-with`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) and [other](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions).

<sup>Note: I haven't tested it, so please suggest improvements if you do.</sup>